# How to calculate working hours in Bigquery where we are not capturing Login Logout time but the timestamp of the case resolve time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have data like below table

| Reviewer Name | Case Submission Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| reviewer1 | 28/03/2022 5:00:02 PM |
| reviewer1 | 28/03/2022 5:00:19 PM |
| reviewer1 | 28/03/2022 5:00:25 PM |
| reviewer1 | 28/03/2022 6:00:02 PM |
| reviewer1 | 29/03/2022 11:00:02 PM |
| reviewer1 | 29/03/2022 2:00:02 AM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 11:00:02 AM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 12:00:02 PM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 1:00:02 PM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 1:30:02 PM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 2:00:02 PM |
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 2:30:02 PM |

Each reviewer are working in different shifts, some are working in day shift some are in night shift (where shift is starting in one day and ending in next day). We are calculating difference between 2 timestamp to calculate time spent in each case. As some shifts are starting in one day and ending in next day hence we can partition by day.

Expected output:
| Reviewer Name | login Timestamp      | logout Timestamp     |Active Time  |
| :------------ | :-------------------: | :------------------: | --------: |
| reviewer1     | 28/03/2022 5:00:02 PM | 29/03/2022 2:00:02 AM| **Time difference between each timestamps between login and logout time**|
| reviewer2 | 28/03/2022 11:00:02 AM    |28/03/2022 2:30:02 PM| |

**How to calculate shift time of each analyst day-wise(starting day will be shift day) in Bigquery.**

I tried using lag function partitioning by day and took all the entries where time difference between time and lag-time less than 8hours, this is giving an overview but not the correct number.

Comment: SQL Server <> Google BigQuery - please correct your tags.

Comment: Maybe some example output

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)